# Microcontroller communication tasks in background

Tags: communication, microcontroller

I'm using an ARM Cortex M4 and I want to ask if it's possible to unload main routine form communication tasks and let them run in background.

For example I'm using on ARM MCU this peripherals:

- ADC
- I2C
- UART
- SPI

When adc_start(ADC); is called, ADC start conversion in background so I don't need to wait until ADC has finished conversion and I can go to the next istruction and later read the ADC result.

I want to ask if it's possible to do the same with communication periphericals. I2C and SPI can be fast, but since this MCU types can reach 50Mhz and more, it's a waste of MCU speed if I need to wait until I2C have finished to trasmit at 400kHz or SPI at 20Mhz or worst with UART. Also, if I perform some tasks and I don't want to interrupt them, I need to be able to unload MCU from any interrupts from peripherals and let them recive packets, buffer them and when I need to read them.

Something like this is possible?

Comment: Interrupts are the key to avoid wasting processor time waiting for events - especially when you have many hardware events. Don't program the minutiae of hardware events in `main`. Let the interrupts handle that and flag the main, or make a callback, when a task has a conclusion relevant to the main flow, for example when an ADC conversion has a result, or when a serial input has a complete message buffered, or a buffered serial output has completed transmission. But the question is far too broad to answer easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood the question correctly, you're looking for automatic interrupt based handling of fast communication peripherals such as the I2C and SPI. As far as I know, YES! its achievable, at least on the Texas Instruments TIVA based ARM CORTEX M4 series MCUs. It's quite a nifty little feature to have around when you're working on computationally intensive algorithms and not have the CPU bogged down on waiting for the SPI to finish its task.
For a good reference on programming the CORTEX M4 peripherals, I recommend keeping this book handy: 
[http://www.amazon.com/TI-ARM-Peripherals-Programming-Interfacing-ebook/dp/B00L9DRAI2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00L9DRAI2)

Table 6-7 in chapter 6 of the book details the interrupt vector table on the TM4C123G MCU (the one shipped with the TIVA launchpad). Interrupts 50 and 53 are assignments for the SSI/SPI and I2C peripherals respectively. Process should be fairly straight forward once you unmask the right interrupts.